# Java local class with lambda behaves differently on different machines, why?

Tags: java, lambda

The following piece of code was executed on 2 different machines. On one machine, it executes without any issues but it throws a java.lang.VerifyError on the other. Please note that the JVM version was the same (jdk_8u20_x64) on both machines.

```
@Test
public void testLocal() throws Exception {
    class Foo implements Runnable {
        @Override public void run() {}
    }

    List<String> values = Collections.emptyList();
    List<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<>();

    values.forEach(r -> runnables.add(new Foo()));
}
```

- Processor on machine 1: Intel Code i5 CPU 650 @ 3.20GHz
- Processor on machine 2: Intel Code i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz

One machine 1, the code block executes fine but on machine 2, it throws "java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack"

I can of course rewrite the code to make it work in both cases but I am just curious to know why this code shows the erratic behavior.

**Update**: Following Mark Rotteveel's advice, I tried to run this code with the latest JDK (jdk_8u112_x64). On both these machines, the code runs just fine.

Comment: Java 8 update 20 is pretty old (update 121 was released recently), you might want to consider upgrading first before you start chasing bugs that might have been long since fixed.

Comment: *"Please note that the JVM version was the same (jdk_8u20_x64) on both machines"* Given the error, that seems unlikely. It's *really easy* to have multiple JVMs on a machine and not be using the one you think you're using.

Comment: Did you read the responses from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365106/reason-for-the-exception-java-lang-verifyerror-bad-type-on-operand-stack?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your comment but I ran the code from within eclipse on both machines and eclipse shows which JVM the code is running on. So I am pretty certain the code running on jdk_8u20_x64.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I'll try to run this code with the latest JDK and post the result in here.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, make sure you use the same class files on both machines, or make sure you use the same Eclipse version. Eclipse has its own compiler, and it doesn't always produce correct bytecode (especially around the start of new Java versions).

Comment: That’s strange. There has been a bug in `javac` related to inner classes which has been fixed in `8u40`, however, it doesn’t break your specific example. On the other hand, if you used Eclipse and its ECJ is responsible, there is no explanation why updating the jdk helped…