# Maven fails on passing state into an inner class through lambdas in a plugin context

Tags: java, maven, lambda, classloader, inner-classes

Here is a small "hello world" application to demonstrate the subject:

```
class GreetingFactory {

    private final String welcomingWord;
    private final String recipient;

    GreetingFactory(Supplier<String> welcomingWord, Supplier<String> recipient) {
        this.welcomingWord = welcomingWord.get();
        this.recipient = recipient.get();
    }

    String getGreeting() {
        return welcomingWord + " " + recipient;
    }
}

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.sayHi();
    }

    private final String welcomingWord = "hello";
    private final String recipient = "world";
    private class InnerGreetingFactory extends GreetingFactory {
        InnerGreetingFactory() {
            super(() -> welcomingWord, () -> recipient);
        }
    }
    private final GreetingFactory greetingFactory = new InnerGreetingFactory();

    private void sayHi() {
        System.out.println(greetingFactory.getGreeting());
    }
}
```

Everyting's OK when it runs directly in JVM. Problems appear when it's executed within a Maven plugin:

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>playgrounds.maven.exec.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

Execution fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal field name "playgrounds.maven.exec.App$this" in class playgrounds/maven/exec/App$InnerGreetingFactory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:270)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The problem vanishes if `GreetingFactory` is instantiated directly, without subclassing:

```
private final GreetingFactory greetingFactory = new GreetingFactory(() -> welcomingWord, () -> recipient);
```

or if `GreetingFactory` is refactored to receive strings instead of suppliers in the constructor:

```
GreetingFactory(String welcomingWord, String recipient) {
    this.welcomingWord = welcomingWord;
    this.recipient = recipient;
}

...

private final String welcomingWord = "hello";
private final String recipient = "world";
private class InnerGreetingFactory extends GreetingFactory {
    InnerGreetingFactory() {
        super(welcomingWord, recipient);
    }
}
private final GreetingFactory greetingFactory = new InnerGreetingFactory();
```

The issue is reproducible on Maven 3.3.9, 3.5.0 and 3.5.2 with JDK 1.8.0_152 on Windows 7.

`sql-maven-plugin` fails in a very similar way while executing Java code of a H2 trigger with a close class structure. So it's not a problem specific to `exec-maven-plugin`.

Is it a bug or a known limitation of Maven classloading or something else? Has somebody faced with such error? Are there some workarounds?

**EDIT:** well, it's not Maven.

Looks like the root cause is in `java.net.URLClassLoader` which is used by `exec-maven-plugin` to load the `App$InnerGreetingFactory` class. So the error can be reproduced without Maven at all with the following code:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL('file:/path/to/jar/with/helloworld/app.jar')}, null);
classLoader.loadClass("playgrounds.maven.exec.App$InnerGreetingFactory");
```

When the app is started with `java -jar ...`, JVM uses `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` to load the class. That's why the app runs well there.

Further investigation has shown that `URLClassLoader` fails to load the `App$InnerGreetingFactory` class only if it's compiled with `vars` debug info.

Oracle JDK bug?

Comment: Why `super(() -> welcomingWord, () -> recipient)` and not just `super(welcomingWord, recipient)`?

Comment: @JimGarrison Just to reproduce the error. In the demo app it doesn't make much sense. But in the code I faced with the problem first lambdas can't be eliminated in the same way.

Comment: Lambda expressions accessing the outer instance before the super constructor has been called… reminds me on [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30365106/2711488). In that case, it’s about compiler bugs and using a different compiler version might make a difference. But it’s hard to believe that using `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` instead of `URLClassLoader` makes a difference, at least in Java 8, `Launcher$AppClassLoader` is a subclass of `URLClassLoader` and the error is thrown by the `private native` method `ClassLoader.defineClass1` anyway…