# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack Java 8 121 but not on Java 11

Tags: java, exception, java-8, java-11

I know that a fix was made on Java 8 Build 75 https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8006684 and I cannot reproduce the same problem with the code that break on version before 75. But this code is throwing the exception on Java 8-121 but not on Java 11. In which version of the JDK was this problem solved?

A example this code was generating the problem on versions before 75 but not afterwards.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    xxx();
}
static void xxx() {
    Functional1 f  = () -> {
        Object o = new Object() { };
        return new A();
    };
}
static class A { }
static interface Functional1 { A func(); }
```

But my code is throwing the exception on Java 8-121 but not on Java 11.

The code is just a example of the real code to be able to represent it but still in a single way.

```
class Element{
    private final String data;
    public Element(final String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }    
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }    
}

class Html{
    protected Element doSomething(final String data){
        return new Element(data);
    }
}

class A{
    protected final Html html = new Html();
}
class B extends A{}
class C extends B{}
class D extends C{}
class E extends D{}

public final class JavaBug extends E{
    private final List<SupplierElementWithMapper>data = Arrays.asList(new SupplierElementWithMapper(""));
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        System.out.println("JavaVersion: "+System.getProperty("java.version"));
        final JavaBug clazz = new JavaBug();        
    }
    
    private final class SupplierElementWithMapper{
        private final Supplier<Element> supplier;
        private final Function<Element,String> mapper;
        private UnaryOperator<String> unaryOperator = UnaryOperator.identity();

        public SupplierElementWithMapper(final String selector) {
            this(()->html.doSomething(selector),Element::getData);
        }
        public SupplierElementWithMapper(final Supplier<Element> supplier,final Function<Element, String> mapper) {
            this.supplier = supplier;
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        private SupplierElementWithMapper addUnaryOperator(final UnaryOperator<String>unaryOperator){
            this.unaryOperator = unaryOperator;
            return this;
        }    
    }    
}
```

The console

```
JavaVersion: 1.8.0_121
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    projectname/issues/JavaBug$SupplierElementWithMapper.lambda$new$1(Ljava/lang/String;Lprojectname/issues/JavaBug;)Lprojectname/issues/Element; @1: getfield
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/String' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'projectname/issues/JavaBug$SupplierElementWithMapper'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @1
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/lang/String', 'projectname/issues/JavaBug' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/String' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0005 b400 102a b600 11b0          

    at projectname.issues.JavaBug.<init>(JavaBug.java:34)
    at projectname.issues.JavaBug.main(JavaBug.java:37)
C:\Users\JavIut\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

The problem is this line in the supplier.

```
this(()->html.doSomething(selector),Element::getData);
```

Is calling a protected member i have try with no success.

```
this(()->{return html.doSomething(selector);},Element::getData);
this(()->JavaBug.super.html.doSomething(selector),Element::getData);
this(()->getHtml().doSomething(selector),Element::getData);/*ADDING IN THE CODE THE GETTER*/
```

But this works.

```
this(()->JavaBug.this.html.doSomething(selector),Element::getData);
```

How can I find in which version this fix was made? I need to inform into my team.

In the IntelliJ idea prompt states that *Source code don't match bytecode*

Same problem with 121 https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/verifyerror-bad-type-on-operand-stack/50700

I think the solution might be this.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8178444

```
FULL PRODUCT VERSION :
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
javac 1.8.0_121


ADDITIONAL OS VERSION INFORMATION :
OSX 10.12.4 (16E195)
16.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.5.0: Fri Mar  3 16:52:33 PST 2017; root:xnu-3789.51.2~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64


A DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM :
See code snippet below.

STEPS TO FOLLOW TO REPRODUCE THE PROBLEM :
Run the provided code.
```

Comment: Don't know. Why are your team members using ancient versions of the Java compiler? Note the bug was in `javac`, so you would have to be using truly ancient pre-compiled classes.

Comment: yes i do the same question to myself every single day mate :(

Comment: Just do bisect searching. You can download all Java versions from Oracle website. Should not take too long.

Comment: Have you tried with a later Java 8 version, e.g. [8u202](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html) or [8u241](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) (as of Apr 3, 2020)?

Comment: i will do it now mate thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is an instance of [JDK-8184989](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8184989):

> The fix for <strike>[JDK-8129740](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8129740)</strike> is incomplete. It fails on cases when outer class is a subclass and the entities of it's [sic] superclass are referred to in lambda expression.

This bug has been close with “Fix Version/s: 10” and I can indeed reproduce your problem with JDK-9.0.4 but not with JDK-10.0.2.

The referenced [JDK-8129740](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8129740) is the bug report linked in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30365106/2711488) you already backlinked via a comment.