# Android Studio version 2020.3.1 crashes automatically after one minute

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have just updated android studio with latest version 2020.3.1. When I try to launch the studio the application crashes automatically with below error:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/IntArrays.lambda$parallelRadixSortIndirect$1(Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger;ILjava/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue;[I[IZ[I)Ljava/lang/Void; @138: iushr
  Reason:
    Type double_2nd (current frame, stack[4]) is not assignable to integer
  Current Frame:
    bci: @138
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger', integer, 'java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue', '[I', '[I', integer, '[I', '[I', '[I', 'it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/IntArrays$Segment', integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer }
    stack: { '[I', integer, float, double, double_2nd }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 1101 00bc 0a3a 0711 0100 bc0a 3a08 2ab6
    0000010: 0159 9a00 191b 3609 1509 8409 ff99 000e
    0000020: 2cb2 015b b600 f257 a7ff f02c b601 5fc0
    0000030: 00ee 3a09 1909 b201 5ba6 0005 01b0 1909
    0000040: b401 6136 0a19 09b4 0165 360b 1909 b401
    0000050: 6836 0c15 0c07 709a 0009 1100 80a7 0004
    0000060: 0336 0d06 150c 0770 6410 0868 360e 150a
    0000070: 150b 6036 0f15 0f84 0fff 150a 9f00 1e19
    0000080: 072d 1904 150f 2e2e 0b0e 7c11 00ff 7e15
    0000090: 0d82 5c2e 0460 4fa7 ffde 0236 0f03 3610
    00000a0: 150a 3611 1510 1101 00a2 0025 1907 1510
    00000b0: 2e99 0007 1510 360f 1908 1510 1511 1907
    00000c0: 1510 2e60 5936 114f 8410 01a7 ffd9 1505
    00000d0: 9900 b715 0a15 0b60 3610 1510 8410 ff15
    00000e0: 0a9f 0027 1906 1908 2d19 0415 102e 2e0b
    00000f0: 0e7c 1100 ff7e 150d 825c 2e04 645b 4f19
    0000100: 0415 102e 4fa7 ffd5 1906 150a 1904 150a
    0000110: 150b b800 1f03 3610 150a 3611 1510 150f
    0000120: a300 5e15 0c06 a200 4819 0715 102e 04a4
    0000130: 003f 1907 1510 2e11 0400 a200 1819 042d
    0000140: 1511 1511 1907 1510 2e60 1505 b801 2aa7
    0000150: 001f 2ab6 016b 572c bb00 ee59 1511 1907
    0000160: 1510 2e15 0c04 60b7 00f0 b600 f257 1511
    0000170: 1907 1510 2e60 3611 8410 01a7 ffa1 1907
    0000180: 03b8 012e a700 d815 0a15 0b60 1907 150f
    0000190: 2e64 3610 150a 3611 0236 1215 1115 10a3
    00001a0: 00bd 1904 1511 2e36 142d 1514 2e0b 0e7c
    00001b0: 1100 ff7e 150d 8236 1215 1115 10a2 0041
    00001c0: 1908 1512 5c2e 0464 5b4f 5936 1315 11a4
    00001d0: 0028 1514 3615 1904 1513 2e36 1419 0415
    00001e0: 1315 154f 2d15 142e 0b0e 7c11 00ff 7e15
    00001f0: 0d82 3612 a7ff cc19 0415 1115 144f 150c
    0000200: 06a2 0048 1907 1512 2e04 a400 3f19 0715
    0000210: 122e 1104 00a2 0018 1904 2d15 1115 1119
    0000220: 0715 122e 6015 05b8 012a a700 1f2a b601
    0000230: 6b57 2cbb 00ee 5915 1119 0715 122e 150c
    0000240: 0460 b700 f0b6 00f2 5715 1119 0715 122e
    0000250: 6036 1119 0715 1203 4fa7 ff42 2ab6 016e
    0000260: 57a7 fdad                              
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@14,Object[#75],Object[#75])
    append_frame(@24,Integer)
    chop_frame(@43,1)
    append_frame(@62,Object[#238])
    append_frame(@96,Integer,Integer,Integer)
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@97,Integer)
    append_frame(@117,Integer,Integer,Integer)
    chop_frame(@154,1)
    append_frame(@164,Integer,Integer,Integer)
    same_frame(@184)
    chop_frame(@206,2)
    append_frame(@218,Integer)
    chop_frame(@264,1)
    append_frame(@284,Integer,Integer)
    same_frame(@338)
    same_frame(@366)
    chop_frame(@382,2)
    same_frame(@391)
    append_frame(@411,Integer,Integer,Integer)
    append_frame(@448,Top,Integer)
    full_frame(@503,{Object[#246],Integer,Object[#235],Object[#75],Object[#75],Integer,Object[#75],Object[#75],Object[#75],Object[#238],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer},{})
    full_frame(@510,{Object[#246],Integer,Object[#235],Object[#75],Object[#75],Integer,Object[#75],Object[#75],Object[#75],Object[#238],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Top,Integer},{})
    same_frame(@557)
    chop_frame(@585,2)
    chop_frame(@604,3)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:645)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1705)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/IntArrays.lambda$parallelRadixSortIndirect$1(Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger;ILjava/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue;[I[IZ[I)Ljava/lang/Void; @138: iushr
  Reason:
    Type double_2nd (current frame, stack[4]) is not assignable to integer
  Current Frame:
    bci: @138
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger', integer, 'java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue', '[I', '[I', integer, '[I', '[I', '[I', 'it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/IntArrays$Segment', integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer }
    stack: { '[I', integer, float, double, double_2nd }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 1101 00bc 0a3a 0711 0100 bc0a 3a08 2ab6
    0000010: 0159 9a00 191b 3609 1509 8409 ff99 000e
    0000020: 2cb2 015b b600 f257 a7ff f02c b601 5fc0
    0000030: 00ee 3a09 1909 b201 5ba6 0005 01b0 1909
    0000040: b401 6136 0a19 09b4 0165 360b 1909 b401
    0000050: 6836 0c15 0c07 709a 0009 1100 80a7 0004
    0000060: 0336 0d06 150c 0770 6410 0868 360e 150a
    0000070: 150b 6036 0f15 0f84 0fff 150a 9f00 1e19
    0000080: 072d 1904 150f 2e2e 0b0e 7c11 00ff 7e15
    0000090: 0d82 5c2e 0460 4fa7 ffde 0236 0f03 3610
    00000a0: 150a 3611 1510 1101 00a2 0025 1907 1510
    00000b0: 2e99 0007 1510 360f 1908 1510 1511 1907
    00000c0: 1510 2e60 5936 114f 8410 01a7 ffd9 1505
    00000d0: 9900 b715 0a15 0b60 3610 1510 8410 ff15
    00000e0: 0a9f 0027 1906 1908 2d19 0415 102e 2e0b
    00000f0: 0e7c 1100 ff7e 150d 825c 2e04 645b 4f19
    0000100: 0415 102e 4fa7 ffd5 1906 150a 1904 150a
    0000110: 150b b800 1f03 3610 150a 3611 1510 150f
    0000120: a300 5e15 0c06 a200 4819 0715 102e 04a4
    0000130: 003f 1907 1510 2e11 0400 a200 1819 042d
    0000140: 1511 1511 1907 1510 2e60 1505 b801 2aa7
    0000150: 001f 2ab6 016b 572c bb00 ee59 1511 1907
    0000160: 1510 2e15 0c04 60b7 00f0 b600 f257 1511
    0000170: 1907 1510 2e60 3611 8410 01a7 ffa1 1907
    0000180: 03b8 012e a700 d815 0a15 0b60 1907 150f
    0000190: 2e64 3610 150a 3611 0236 1215 1115 10a3
    00001a0: 00bd 1904 1511 2e36 142d 1514 2e0b 0e7c
    00001b0: 1100 ff7e 150d 8236 1215 1115 10a2 0041
    00001c0: 1908 1512 5c2e 0464 5b4f 5936 1315 11a4
    00001d0: 0028 1514 3615 1904 1513 2e36 1419 0415
    00001e0: 1315 154f 2d15 142e 0b0e 7c11 00ff 7e15
    00001f0: 0d82 3612 a7ff cc19 0415 1115 144f 150c
    0000200: 06a2 0048 1907 1512 2e04 a400 3f19 0715
    0000210: 122e 1104 00a2 0018 1904 2d15 1115 1119
    0000220: 0715 122e 6015 05b8 012a a700 1f2a b601
    0000230: 6b57 2cbb 00ee 5915 1119 0715 122e 150c
    0000240: 0460 b700 f0b6 00f2 5715 1119 0715 122e
    0000250: 6036 1119 0715 1203 4fa7 ff42 2ab6 016e
    0000260: 57a7 fdad                              
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@14,Object[#75],Object[#75])
    append_frame(@24,Integer)
    chop_frame(@43,1)
    append_frame(@62,Object[#238])
    append_frame(@96,Integer,Integer,Integer)
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@97,Integer)
    append_frame(@117,Integer,Integer,Integer)
    chop_frame(@154,1)
    append_frame(@164,Integer,Integer,Integer)
    same_frame(@184)
    chop_frame(@206,2)
    append_frame(@218,Integer)
    chop_frame(@264,1)
    append_frame(@284,Integer,Integer)
    same_frame(@338)
    same_frame(@366)
    chop_frame(@382,2)
    same_frame(@391)
    append_frame(@411,Integer,Integer,Integer)
    append_frame(@448,Top,Integer)
    full_frame(@503,{Object[#246],Integer,Object[#235],Object[#75],Object[#75],Integer,Object[#75],Object[#75],Object[#75],Object[#238],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer},{})
    full_frame(@510,{Object[#246],Integer,Object[#235],Object[#75],Object[#75],Integer,Object[#75],Object[#75],Object[#75],Object[#238],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Top,Integer},{})
    same_frame(@557)
    chop_frame(@585,2)
    chop_frame(@604,3)

    at it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.ints.IntArrayList.<init>(IntArrayList.java:86)
    at com.intellij.util.graph.DFSTBuilder.<init>(DFSTBuilder.java:29)
    at com.intellij.util.graph.DFSTBuilder.<init>(DFSTBuilder.java:46)
    at com.intellij.util.graph.DFSTBuilder.<init>(DFSTBuilder.java:39)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.checkPluginCycles(PluginManagerCore.java:691)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1058)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadAndInitializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1358)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.lambda$initPlugins$15(PluginManagerCore.java:816)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
    ... 9 more

-----
Your JRE: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64 (Oracle Corporation)
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
```

Not sure why this the application crashes. Please help me if there is any open issue with the current.
Also, any sort of resolution would help. Thanks!

Comment: check this,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365106/reason-for-the-exception-java-lang-verifyerror-bad-type-on-operand-stack

Comment: check this also,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021950/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-verifyerror-bad-type-on-operand-stack-java