# BiPredicate lambda is causing a java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack, how do I fix this?

Tags: java, runtime-error, minecraft

For some reason, it's saying `Type 'java/lang/Object' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/Boolean'`, yet I'm pretty sure it's not returning an Object anywhere in the BiPredicate, not that the code would be called yet anyways.
I've tried debugging it, haven't had any luck getting debug points to hit, even a debug point on the constructor didn't get hit.

```java
public static SlotType<SlotInput> IT_IN = new SlotType<>("item_in", (type, gui, inv, i, d) -> new SlotInput(type, gui, inv.getOrDefault(type, new EmptyHandler()), i, d.getX(), d.getY()), (t, i) -> {
        if (t instanceof TileEntityMachine) {
            return (((TileEntityMachine<?>) t).recipeHandler.map(rh -> rh.accepts(i)).orElse(true));
        }
        return true;
    }, ContentEvent.ITEM_INPUT_CHANGED, true, false);
```

seems as soon as the class loads it crashes with the error

```java
public SlotType(String id, ISlotSupplier<T> slotSupplier, BiPredicate<IGuiHandler, ItemStack> validator, ContentEvent ev, boolean input, boolean output) {
        this.id = id;
        this.slotSupplier = slotSupplier;
        this.output = output;
        this.tester = validator;
        this.input = input;
        this.ev = ev;
        AntimatterAPI.register(SlotType.class, this);
    }
```

here is the link to the class on GitHub:
https://github.com/GregTech-Intergalactical/AntimatterAPI/blob/dev/src/main/java/muramasa/antimatter/gui/SlotType.java
oh and here's the full crash for reference: https://gist.github.com/Trinsdar/bba054869f1c565a32d61bb60cc31bda

Update: changing the lambda in IT_IN to a custom implementation of BiPredicate seems to have caused it to stop crashing, all the others though are just fine, really weird.

Comment: VerifyErrors in Minecraft are usually caused by coremods. Do you have any of those? Does the crash still happen with just this one mod? Also, what if you manually create a class of your own that implements BiPredicate and pass that instead of using a lambda to do it for you? As for breakpoints, remember that a VerifyError will happen when the class is loaded, not when the problem method is called or anything like that.

Comment: Questions related to Minecraft should be labelled `[minecraft]`.  It helps people who have no knowledge of the Minecraft platform (or no interest in it) steer clear.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30365106/10952503) help you with your question ? Also, thanks Stephen, without your edit I will not see this post (i"m watching [tag:minecraft])

Comment: If you solve your issue, you can self-answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems it is definitely an issue with java 8, specifically with it's compiler. I managed to stop the errors by changing the BiPredicate lambda to a custom instance of BiPredicate that implements the code in the lambda, though I will mention I have no idea why the other 9 fields have no issues. This is also fixed by simply using java 11, though that's not an easy alternative for something like jitpack.